# Filter result from JSON based on categories in JQuery AJax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am populating the categories and results but I want if user selects categories then the result should be filtered out based on selection. User can filter the result based on multiple selection as well.

Please see my code here

```
posts": [

{
    "id": 85,
    "type": "post",
    "slug": "article22",
    "url": "http://example.com/tankers/abc/article22/",
    "status": "publish",
    "title": "Article22",
    "title_plain": "Article22",
    "content": "<p>ar 16 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>\n",
    "date": "2014-06-06 15:00:12",
    "modified": "2014-06-06 15:00:12",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 24,
            "slug": "abc",
            "title": "abc",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 23,
            "post_count": 7
        }
    ],
},


{
    "id": 86,
    "type": "post",
    "slug": "article23",
    "url": "http://example.com/tankers/abc/article23/",
    "status": "publish",
    "title": "Article23",
    "title_plain": "Article23",
    "content": "<p>ar 16 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>\n",
    "date": "2014-06-06 15:00:12",
    "modified": "2014-06-06 15:00:12",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 24,
            "slug": "xyz",
            "title": "xyz",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 7
        }
    ],
},
```

Please see my javascript code below

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/get_recent_posts/",
    //force to handle it as text
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(obj){
        var arr = [], //to collect id values 
        collection = []; //collect unique object
        $.each(obj.posts , function(key , value){ // First Level
            $('#posts-articles-parent').append('<li><h2>'+value.title+'</h2></li>' );
            $.each(value.categories , function(k , v ){  // The contents inside stars
                if ($.inArray(v.id, arr) == -1) {
                    arr.push(v.id);
                    if(v.parent == 0){
                        $('#posts-category-parent').append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="chkCategory" checked="true" value="'+v.id+'"/><a>'+v.title+'</a></li>' );
                    } else {
                        $('#posts-category').append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="chkCategory" checked="true" value="'+v.id+'"/><a>'+v.title+'</a></li>' );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Please see my html code

```
<div id="posts-categories-wrapper">
    <ul id="posts-category-parent">
    </ul>
    <ul id="posts-category">
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="posts-articles-wrapper">
    <ul id="posts-articles-parent">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want how can I make the result "value.title" to be filtered out based on the selected category. please see the plnkr link plnkr.co/edit/8OlPCUMuLfZBFry63kEb?p=preview. I want how to write the functionality to filter out the result if i select any category

Comment: I can't get out the question in your post.

Comment: Oh.. I want how can I make the result "value.title" to be filtered out based on the selected category. please see the plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/8OlPCUMuLfZBFry63kEb?p=preview. I want how to write the functionality to filter out the result if i select any category